# Ruby CLI: Prompt for root password and continue executing script as root?

Tags: ruby, sudo

Other than requiring the user to invoke a ruby script through `sudo`, is there a way to start running a script as a regular user, then at some point during runtime, elevate privileges to root, by prompting the user for their root password?

Maybe something along the lines of `#exec` using the current command prefixed with sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. It just uses exec to call itself (`test_script` in this case) again. But be very careful to make sure that it doesn't run infinitely by adding a condition which will call `exit`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV[0] == "--second"
  puts "...called again and exiting."
  exit
end

puts "Calling self again..."
exec "sudo ./test_script --second"
```