# Is it possible to acknowledge and respond to a command line prompt?

Tags: ruby, shell, sudo

For example, I create a `Shell` object to execute some shell command (maybe a sudo command) and it prompts me for a password.

Does Ruby have the ability to acknowledge this prompt and can I send it a password?

Comment: If you need to to run a command via `sudo`, then you should configure `/etc/sudoers` file for specific user/group instead of trying to input the password via script

Comment: I would want to be able to run command via `sudo` on a 'random/any' computer.

Comment: There's some [suggestions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498536/how-do-you-prompt-for-a-sudo-password-using-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

If you supply the whole dialogue from your program, you could use [Net::Telnet](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Net/Telnet.html).

If you want to pass the control back to the user, you could either use the [ruby/expect](https://github.com/abates/ruby_expect) gem, or shell out to an [Expect](http://inguza.com/document/expect-and-tcl-mini-reference-manual) script. In both cases, you need to have Tcl/Expect installed (which is likely the case anyway).