# Can Ruby interact with my root privileges?

Tags: ruby, sudo, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

This is my first question here, please tell me if I can in some way tag it better or make a better question :)

I'm trying to make a ruby script to install some packages and edit some configurations after I format a computer. I use Manjaro Linux, and my script can already install the official Arch packages, but when it comes to AUR (with Yay) I sometimes receive an error message, saying that Yay can't run as sudo. Also I saw that some people can integrate their Shell with other scripting languages, I started this, but still need to type my Root password more than I want to.

I searched for help on this and found that Python have a library called Pexpct, but didn't found any Ruby alternatives to it. I saw somethings related to Ruby's Expect and IO, but couldn't understand how and when to use it.

```rb
programs = [
  "zsh",
  "zathura",
  "zathura-cb",
  "zathura-djvu",
  "zathura-pdf-mupdf",
  "zathura-ps",
  "texlive-most",
  "texlive-lang",
  "geogebra",
  "vim",
  "yay",
  "adobe-source-code-pro-fonts",
  "firefox-developer-edition"
]

#Array iteration to install Arch official repo's packages
programs.each do |name|
  system ("pacman -Sq #{name} --noconfirm")
end
```

I want to know if in some way can this code inside the programs block insert my password. I know it has a lot of security problems, but is on this case for this one snippet of code and study cases. I won't use it on other scripts.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695743/8008340 - I believe this is a much better way

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov it's perfect, thanks :)

Comment: There's a nice summary of alternatives [here](https://www.hilman.io/blog/2016/01/stop-using-backtick-to-run-shell-command-in-ruby/)